# Can some one help me with this error?

Tags: c++, error-handling

I have to write this program as an assignment. I've been struct with the following error for a week now.Thank in advance.

#### ========Error list==============

```
1. x,w,y is undefined.
 2. For checkin/checkout it says "declaration is in compatible with void employee::checkin/checkout(int,int,int)"
 3. In this->Time(a,b,c) it's said type name is not allowed.
```

P.S. If there is anyway to improve it or something need fixing please tell me that would be very great. Thanks again in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#define N 2
using namespace std;
class Time
{
private:int h,m,s;
public:
    void time_diff(Time T1,Time T2)
    {   
        Time t;
            t.s=(60+T2.s-T1.s)%60;
            t.m=(60+T2.m-T1.m+(1-(60+T2.s-T1.s)/60))%60;
            t.h=T2.h-T1.h+(1-(60+T2.m-T1.m+(1-(60+T2.s-T1.s)/60))/60);
            t.h=t.h<0?t.h+=24:t.h;
            *this=t;
    }

    Time(int hh=0,int mm=0,int ss=0){
            s=ss%60;
            m=(mm+ss/60)%60;
            h=(hh+(mm+ss/60)/60)%24;
    }

    void set_time(int a,int b,int c){
        this->Time(a,b,c);  
    }
    double converter(int hn,int m,int s)
    {
        int hn,mn,sn;
        hn=h*3600;
        mn=m*60;
        sn=hn+mn+s;
        return sn;
    }
};
class employee
{
    int id;
    
protected:
    Time t_in,t_out;
    double wage;
public:
    employee(int=0,double=5);
    void checkin(int,int,int);//set t_in
    void checkout(int,int,int);//set t_out  
    void display();//display id and total time at work (t_out-t_in ) 
};
employee::employee(int w,double x)
{
    x=wage;
    w=id;
}
class staff:public employee{
public:
    double get_paid();//wage*(t_out-t_in);
    staff(int=0,int=5);//id,wage
};
void employee::checkin()
{
    t_in.set_time(x,w,y);
}
void employee::checkout()
{
    t_out.set_time(x,w,y);
}
double staff::get_paid()
{
    int paid,load;
    Time wo;
    wo.time_diff(t_out,t_in);
    load=wo.converter;
    paid=load*wage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need set_time, try this::

```
class Time
{
    ...
    void set_time(int a, int b, int c) {
         *this = new Time(a, b, c);
    }
    ...
}
```

... however I think set_time is useless because you have the constructor already.

In checkin/checkout implementation you have to repeat the same firm of the declaration, so:

```
void employee::checkin(int x, int w, int y)
{
    t_in.set_time(x, w, y);
}
void employee::checkout(int x, int w, int y)
{
    t_out.set_time(x, w, y);
}
```

Indeed the constructor employee is wrong because you set local arguments x and w with the same values of member fields wage and id but these values are zeros and remain so.
You would probably like do the inverse, so:

```
employee::employee(int w, double x)
{
    wage = x;
    id = w;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and response to my question.I'll try it out right away